# How to give scopes in AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth and get extra data from facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, dotnetopenauth

I'm Creating a site with external login, I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth for add external login, the code in AuthConfig.cs is,

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddFacebook(
            appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBID"],
            appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBKEY"]
            );
```

I need to get some extended permissions like read_stream, publish_stream, etc.,

Is there a way to do that? I googled but all I could find is that we can add Icon instead of text.

Someebody please help me with this!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, somebody give some info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work although there is a provision to add extra data as per many developers. Some say this feature worked before but subsequently dropped due to one of facebook policy which asks developers to ask basic and publish scope differently.

```
//following code will not work, although option is given
var extraData= new Dictionary<string, object>();
        extraData.Add("scope",
                               "email,publish_actions,create_event");
        //facebookSocialData.Add("perms", "status_update");
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
             "xxxx",
             "yyyy", "Facebook", extraData);
```

My suggestion is to make your own custom methods which will allow you to set custom scope or just pull the source of dotnetopenauth and change its code to suite your project.